# CLCircularRegion Can’t use method initWithCenter

Tags: rubymotion

Im trying to use CLCircularRegion.alloc.initWithCenter but i get undefined method...the method is listed when i use .init + tab, i can't figure out why this is happening.

Another issue that i find out is that there is no radius= method, so when i do

```
c = CLCircularRegion.new
```

i have the c.radius (that by default is 0.0) but if i want to change this value i don't have any away to do that, there is no c.radius= method.

Any thoughts about what is happening here, or another way to inicialize a CLCircularRegion with radius?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the rubymotion forum...

```
center_coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(0.0, 0.0)
CLCircularRegion.alloc.initWithCenter(center_coordinate, radius: 1000.0, identifier: 'SomeID')
```

The radius= issue is basically because it's a read only property, so there is no setter method.

You can find the post and answer here:

http://community.rubymotion.com/t/clcircularregion-cant-use-method-initwithcenter/715